# SVN - Automatically generate unique ID for every versioned file

Tags: file, svn, version-control, guid, uniqueidentifier

Is there an unique identifier for every versioned file in an SVN repository? If yes, can it be read using some `svn` command? If no, is it possible to generate one on every `svn add` call?

For example, if I have a GUID generator application, can I call it on every `svn add`, and somehow bind its output (the new GUID) tightly to the added file? Storing it locally is not enough: the unique ID must be stored on the SVN server, because we must be able to download it during every `svn checkout` and `svn update`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an unique identifier for every versioned file in an SVN repository?

No, in common sense. Why do you want to have it? Theoretically, URL of file can be such UUID, or URL@PEG, if you have to have ID for content, not just location

> If yes, can it be read using some svn command?

`svn info URL/OF/FILE` may help

```
>svn info https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/proofsheets.natasha/readme.textile
Path: readme.textile
Name: readme.textile
URL: https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/proofsheets.natasha/readme.textile
Relative URL: ^/readme.textile
Repository Root: https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/proofsheets.natasha
Repository UUID: 3f205b2a-3c6b-4d59-9930-a6250b31609f
Revision: 5
Node Kind: file
Last Changed Author: lazybadger
Last Changed Rev: 2
Last Changed Date: 2013-11-28 00:13:01 +0600 (Чт, 28 ноя 2013)
```

You can use `URL` (globally unique), `Relative URL` (repo-wide unique), `Repository UUID+Relative URL` (globally unique)

> if I have a GUID generator application, can I call it on every svn add

You can call it *after add and before commit*

> somehow bind its output (the new GUID) tightly to the added file?

Yes. Read about (custom) SVN-properies, propset command, `-F` option of command and use it. As result, you'll get some *versioned* over time data as additional attribute of file, which you can read (propget) and write (propset|propedit) independently from checkout|update

Comment: Thank you. I will try `propset`. The other options are too long, I need something short, like a GUID. Long story short, I have to record the usage of some versioned files in a relational DB, and I'd like to identify the file a record refers to by an ID which is tied to SVN.